# How to respond if validation of submitted data failed in a RESTful webservice?

Tags: php, rest, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful webservice to code and now got to the point where i have to validate the request-date sent to the server while performing a PUT-Method with several entities.

But the big question now is: **How do i response with the (maybe much) validation errors?**

The request method and URL:

```
PUT http://example.dev/app_dev.php/api-1.0/labels.xml
```

The request body (as the server receives it):

```
array(size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=11)
      'id' => string '53' (length=2)
      'name' => string '2222' (length=4)
      'app_domain' => string '11' (length=2)
      [...]
  1 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id' => string '54' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'testname2' (length=9)
      'controllpanel_domain' => string 'testname2' (length=9)
      'label' => string 'testname2' (length=9)
      'app_domain' => string 'testname2' (length=9)
      [...]
```

I currently end up with the following response. HTTP status code is 400.

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <status>
        <![CDATA[error]]>
    </status>
    <code>400</code>
    <text>
        <![CDATA[Bad Request]]>
    </text>
    <message>
        <![CDATA[Unable to validate label entities]]>
    </message>
    <violations>
        <object>
            <object>
                <label>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should not be blank]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </label>
                <controllpanel_domain>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should not be blank]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </controllpanel_domain>
                <app_domain>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value is too short. It should have 3 characters or more]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should be 333 or more]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </app_domain>
            </object>
        </object>
        <object>
            <object>
                <controllpanel_domain>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should be a valid number]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </controllpanel_domain>
                <app_domain>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should be a valid number]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </app_domain>
                <login_left_text>
                    <entry>
                        <violation_message>
                            <![CDATA[This value should not be blank]]>
                        </violation_message>
                    </entry>
                </login_left_text>
            </object>
        </object>
    </violations>
</result>
```

in json:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "code": 400,
    "text": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Unable to validate label entities",
    "violations": [
        {
            "object": {
                "label": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should not be blank"
                    }
                ],
                "controllpanel_domain": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should not be blank"
                    }
                ],
                "app_domain": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value is too short. It should have 3 characters or more"
                    },
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should be 333 or more"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "object": {
                "controllpanel_domain": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should be a valid number"
                    }
                ],
                "app_domain": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should be a valid number"
                    }
                ],
                "login_left_text": [
                    {
                        "violation_message": "This value should not be blank"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Can I respond with better data?**

Answer (score 0):

I would say a `400 Bad Request` would be a good response code in this case, in that the request is just not properly formatted.  You can obviously provide more detail on the validation error in the response body.

Most other 4XX series responses are related to problems with the authentication/authorization of the user, with the resource or method mot being found, or with request headers not being properly sent.

In your case the issue lies with the data sent, thus 400 is probably best response code.